# CKEditor – adding Advisory Title for <a> element

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have problem with CKEditor. I tried creating `<a href="#"></a>` element in CKEditor with advisory title, but I can't do it.

I set this option in modal, tab advenced.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

This my CKEditor configuration:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.toolbar = 'Full_Theme';
    config.toolbar_Full_Theme =
        [
            ['Format','Font','FontSize'],['TextColor'],['BGColor'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
            ['Bold','Italic','Strike'],
            ['NumberedList','BulletedList'],
            ['Outdent','Indent'],
            '/',
            ['Link','Unlink'],
            ['Image'],['Table'],['HorizontalRule'],['VideoImage'],['Source'],['Maximize'],
            ['Undo','Redo'],
        ];

    config.toolbar = 'Simple_Theme';
    config.toolbar_Simple_Theme =
        [
             ['Maximize'],
             ['Undo','Redo'],
             '/',*/
            ['Format','Font','FontSize'],['TextColor'],['BGColor'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
            ['Bold','Italic','Strike'],
            ['NumberedList','BulletedList'],
            ['Outdent','Indent'],
            '/',
            ['Link','Unlink'],
            ['Image'],['Table'],['HorizontalRule'],['VideoImage']
        ];
    config.skin = 'kama_theme';

    config.allowedContent = true;

    config.disallowedContent = 'script';

    config.fullPage = true;

    config.extraPlugins = 'floatpanel,video_image,justify,colorbutton,font,colordialog';
    config.resize_enabled = false;
    config.startupShowBorders = false;
    config.font_names = 'Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
        'Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;' +
        'Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;' +
        'Georgia/Georgia, serif;' +
        'Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;' +
        'Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;' +
        'Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;' +
        'Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
        'Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;' +
        'Calibri (UWAGA czcionka niestandardowa)/Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
    config.autoParagraph    = false;
    config.enterMode        = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.entities_latin   = false;
    config.fillEmptyBlocks  = false;
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/beta/filemanager/ajax-filemanager-new-window/?type=images';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/beta/filemanager/upload-and-return/?type=images';
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl      = '/beta/filemanager/ajax-filemanager-new-window/?type=files';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl      = '/beta/filemanager/upload-and-return/?type=files';
};
```

Comment: Advisory title of which element?

Comment: of 'a'(link) element

Comment: Ok, it's still unclear what you mean. So another question – please open http://nightly.ckeditor.com/15-06-11-06-08/full/samples/replacebycode.html, then click the link button and switch to "Advanced" tab. There you have "Advisory title". Is this what you mean?

Comment: Oops. I can see you mentioned the "Advanced" tab in your question. So the next question – what's wrong with it? If I type there some value the link will have a `title` attribute, so everything seems to work perfectly.

Comment: sory, i'm wrong describe my problem. i have ckeditor with incude link plugin. The plugin have bug. Any attributes from 'advenced' tab dosnt work. When I type in 'id' attribute for link in advenced tab i dosnt display in my source.... Im very embarrassed. Any ideas????

Comment: If it doesn't work and you expect that this is a bug in the editor, then you should report it on http://dev.ckeditor.com with all the details - browser, how to reproduce it (**exact** steps and a working sample on which it happens), etc.

Comment: i resolve my problem connecting with ckeditor. i had bad another plugin which crash my link plugin